# class file for com.mongodb.ServerAddress not found

Tags: java, mongodb

Trying for a "hello world" of sorts from mongo and Java but I cannot build my project.

I downloaded mongo java lib from here:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.0.0/

On the below code I get the following error when building:

```
error: cannot access ServerAddress
            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
  class file for com.mongodb.ServerAddress not found
```

Now, the localhost is on 27017 as it is working perfectly via python and pymongo.

I am adapting some old java code that was inserting into a mysql db, but I think mongo is a much better solution.

Thank you so much for any help.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */



import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;


public class my_mongo_test {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */


    public static void main(String[] args)  {
            HashMap<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
            test.put("A","A");
            mongo_test(test);
    }

        public static void mongo_test(HashMap<String,String> arg){
            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("testDB");
            DBCollection col = db.getCollection("testColl");

            DBObject opt = createDBObject(arg);


        }

        private static DBObject createDBObject(HashMap<String,String> arg) {
            BasicDBObjectBuilder docBuilder = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start();


            for(String s : arg.keySet()){
                docBuilder.append(s, arg.get(s));
            }

            return docBuilder.get();
        }




}
```

Comment: @Raptor I have done my research. Mongo is a much better solution for my use case.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `MongoClient` as suggested by the docs? http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/

Comment: @deyur this was part of debugging. actually the issue was that i had the wrong version of the mongo library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mongodb-driver` has multiple dependencies (`bson` and `mongodb-driver-core`) so you need more than just the `mongodb-driver.jar` for it to work. You can use the uber jar [mongodb-java-driver](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.0/) that contains all the required dependencies.

I recently updated the [installation-guide](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/installation-guide/) to add links to the dependencies in the documentation.

I also just create a [mongodb java quickstart](https://github.com/rozza/mongo-java-quickstart) github repo that has gradle configs and a basic `QuickStart.java` file to help you get up and running!

Comment: Ross - its strange. https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.0/mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar was not working for me but when i downloaded the 2.13 listed above it works perfectly.

Comment: Interesting, unpacking the jar shows its there but you link to the `mongodb-driver` which isn't an uber jar.  I would recommend, if starting new code to use the 3.0 driver and use `getDatabase()` and `Document` rather than the old style `DBObject` and the deprecated `mongo.getDB()`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I would recommend from those pages putting a link to java examples with the proper objects. as a new user i am VERY guilty of taking the path of least resistance - as are others most likely.

Comment: Good idea, I added a link at the bottom of the installation guide to the Quick Tour which only uses the new api.